# Custom payment for Ubercart Drupal module

Tags: drupal, ubercart

I am trying to design a membership site using Drupal Ubercart. The problem is I live in Nigeria and the payments method in the default Ubercart module doesn't support any of the banks in Nigeria.

I was wondering if there is any way to link Ubercart to my local bank account to enable receive payment in Nigeria. I am not a programmer and I am relatively new to Drupal, thus I would really appreciate step by step guidance.

Comment: It seems like you could do some research, [perhaps start here](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=drupal+payment+nigeria)? Then you could also find specific, named payment solutions that work for Nigerian bank accounts, and then search for "<name-of-payment-solution> Nigeria".

Comment: I guess paypal.com may be an option